# Building wheel for pandas (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, pandas, pip, cygwin, failed-installation

I have Cygwin installed on my PC and I am trying to install pandas via the pip installer.
Below are some of the messages I get when installing pandas.

$ pip install pandas

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/cf/1b6917426a9a16fd79d56385d0d907f344188558337d6b81196792f857e9/pandas-0.25.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pandas (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py install for pandas: started
```

If anyone can suggest what I should do to get around this error, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run with the verbose flag: `pip install pandas -vvv`, this will output the complete error log. Add this log to the question.

Comment: Without seeing the complete error it's impossible to say but just a shot in the dark: try installing the `python3.7-devel` package.